# Android Foreground Service Not Starting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service

I am making a Life 360 clone just to learn from and I am having a problem getting the foreground service to start.  I got BroadcastReciever working but I get this error when I start my phone... **"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.m360.client: java.lang.NullPointerException: class name is null"**

My goal is to start sending location data to my server on phone startup.  I do not want to open the app before sending my location data.  Below are the java classes in question.  Thank you for your time :)

***Broadcast Receiver Class***

```
public class client extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MapsActivity act = new MapsActivity();
    public Context context;
    public location Location = new location();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Location.start(context);
    }
}
```

***Android Service Class***

```
public class location extends Service implements LocationListener {
public static double lon, lat;
public void start(Context context) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel( "locationService", "locationChannel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager manager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }

    final Intent emptyIntent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0, emptyIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "locationService")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentTitle("360")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    this.startForeground(1, notification);
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do *not* create an instance of a `Service` yourself. To start a foreground service, call `startForegroundService()`. Your `Notification` logic would go in `onCreate()` of the `Service` subclass. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) for more.

Comment: I put the 'startForgroundService' in my 'Activity' class but i'm a bit confused about the intent so I passed the intent from the receiver class.  I removed the 'start' from the service class and moved everything into the 'onCreate()' but i'm getting the a 'null object reference ' error from the 'startForgroundService()'  Thank you for your time @CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare I got the service working when I start my app but do you have any suggestions on how to get context for "startService()" without having to start the app first? Thanks again

Comment: "do you have any suggestions on how to get context for "startService()" without having to start the app first?"-- what is your trigger for the service to start? Is it the user pressing a button? Is it when the phone boots? Is it something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare `    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent in = new Intent(this, location.class);
        context.startService(in);
   }`  Its in my BroadcastReciever